# APIM security by operation

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to expose our corporate data through APIM for 3rd party vendors to consume. I am being told to give the least amount of access to each vendor to consume for security purposes. If I want to give vendor 1 access to /people and /orders, and vendor 2 access to /people and /shipping, can I use products and subscriptions to permission these operations?

I know i can use validate-jwt on each operation, but then figuring out who has access to what becomes tedious, as well as copying AppIds around.

I also tried making an API for each operation, but the naming of the routs became ugly, due the the API suffix. /people/people makes me want to tear my eyeballs out.

Does anyone have any advice? Is APIM not built to share data out this way? Thanks for your time!

Comment: having the separate apis and then using subscriptions and products to control the access. you will have to be crafty while making routes

Comment: Apparently I am not crafty enough... I keep getting routes like /people/people. With each API requiring a unique suffix, how can I have a structure like /api/people /api/offices?